# in Rective Form nested formControlName not taking value

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to store value in nested reactive form but nested formgroup not taking value

```
this.signupForm=new FormGroup({
  username:new FormControl(),
  email:new FormControl(),
  jobDetail: new FormGroup({
    code:new FormControl(),
    post:new FormControl()
  })
});
```

see all code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgw8tn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two little mistakes:

FormGroupname sould be formGroupName
FormcControlName used for post
   should be formControlName

More details about reactive form in angular https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

Its spelled in camel case `formGroupName` and rest everything is great

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">email</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div formGroupName="jobDetail">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="code">Employee code</label>
          <input type="text" id="code" formControlName="code" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="post">Employee post</label>
          <input type="text" id="post" formcControlName="post" class="form-control">
        </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```